# blinking images on hover with css transition and opacity

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

does anyone know why on webkit browsers (chrome, opera), images on hover are blinking? This case is only on second column. There is an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fxJAk

How can I fix it? Is it only webkit browsers bug? It works properly on firefox and even on Internet Explorer 11.

It's on chrome Version 33.0.1750.146, Opera 20.0.1387.64

Comment: Transitions are memory intensive so perhaps it's the way Chrome renders. Certainly it's redrawing the **whole** li because you have **all** on the transitions. Try limiting thay to **just** opacity. Plus (as a final point) Codepen does have some redrawing issues of it's own, especially when using placeholder images as they have to be recalled each time they are drawn.

Comment: it's doesn't matter it is codepen or not, and if I add transition for the opacity only, is the same strange behavior. I've created this example because I've got this problem on my live develop code.

Comment: I'm not saying that codepen is the **whole** issue just the way Chrome does it's rendering is almost certainly different to the way other browsers do it. Gievn the specificity of the issue, it's probably the Blink rendering engine.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Boecy still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add css rules for img below:

`-webkit-transform:(0);
-moz-transform:(0);
-o-transform:(0);
transform:(0);`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FpwIy

Answer (score 2):

The usual workaround (for WebKit) is to add:

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dohgk)